# Asian url redirection

Tags: ruby, redirect, sinatra

I am trying to setup a redirection of URLs that contain Korean or Japanese characters to their English counterparts in a Sinatra application (ruby). Instead of a 301, I get a 404 response.

Example:

```
http://localhost/ko/blog/%ec%95%b1-%ec%a0%84%ed%99%98%ec%9c%a8%ec%9d%84-%eb%86%92%ec%9d%b4%eb%8a%94-%eb%b0%a9%eb%b2%95 
---> http://localhost/ko/blog/how-to-increase-your-rate
```

This does not redirect:

```rb
get "/ko/blog/%ec%95%b1-%ec%a0%84%ed%99%98%ec%9c%a8%ec%9d%84-%eb%86%92%ec%9d%b4%eb%8a%94-%eb%b0%a9%eb%b2%95" do
  redirect "/ko/blog/how-to-increase-your-rate", 301
end
```

Unsurprisingly (but I was desperate) decoding does not redirect either:

```rb
get "/ko/blog/앱-전환율을-높이는-방법" do
  redirect "/ko/blog/how-to-increase-your-rate", 301
end
```

When I look at the server log, the url requested is exactly this:

```bash
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2023:13:31:33 +0200] "GET /ko/blog/%ec%95%b1-%ec%a0%84%ed%99%98%ec%9c%a8%ec%9d%84-%eb%86%92%ec%9d%b4%eb%8a%94-%eb%b0%a9%eb%b2%95 HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0786
```

How can I get sinatra to recognize the requested url string ?

## Update: the stack

- Ruby 2.7.8
- Sinatra 2.2.3

Comment: Works just fine for me when using `get "/ko/blog/앱-전환율을-높이는-방법" do ...` (Ruby 3.2, Sinatra 3.0.6, Puma 6.3.0)

Comment: same here `127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2023:09:33:30 +0200] "GET /ko/blog/%ec%95%b1-%ec%a0%84%ed%99%98%ec%9c%a8%ec%9d%84-%eb%86%92%ec%9d%b4%eb%8a%94-%eb%b0%a9%eb%b2%95 HTTP/1.1" 301 - 0.0087` (Ruby 3.0.5, sinatra 3.0.6, thin 1.8.2) can you provide more details about your setup?

Comment: Indeed, our website's stack is quite old: ruby 2.7.8 and Sinatra 2.2.3. It seems we need to perform a big upgrade!

Comment: Upgrade done, but alas, the issue remains. It seems this other route takes precedence `get "/blog/:slug" do ...`

Comment: @pixeline you can conditionally redirect based on `params['slug']` within that route's block.